# How to add correct indentation to code from Eclipse templates

Tags: eclipse, templates, javadoc, eclipse-templates

I'm trying to generate a template that adds a List to a Javadoc. My current template (name `ul`) is:

```
<ul>
<li>${cursor}</li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

When typing `ul` and hitting `Ctrl + Space` in the JavaDoc of a method, this results in

```
  /**
   * <ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
   */
```

I'd like to have

```
  /**
   * <ul>
   * <li></li>
   * <li></li>
   * </ul>
   */
```

Is there a way to copy all characters that are before the `ul` and add them to each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=36381

Unfortunately as it is nearly a decade old, I wouldn't expect it to be fixed anytime soon.

Comment: Note the duplicate in Comment 1 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=36381#c1 is actually for a ul template like yours!